# Тег meta. Зачем запрещать индексацию страницы?

Tags: html, вёрстка, теги, индексация, meta

В книге рассказывается про тег `meta`. В том числе про значения его атрибутов `name` и `content`. Если присвоить `name` значение `robots`, то атрибуту `content` можно присвоить значения `index`, `noindex`, `follow` и `nofollow`. Вопрос заключается в следующем: зачем атрибуту `content` присваивать значение `noindex`, т.е. зачем поисковой системе запрещать индексировать страницу?

Comment: Например у вас на странице персональные данные и вы не хотите что бы их можно было увидеть в поисковиках

Comment: Либо при заходе на страницу, запускаются тяжелые скрипты. И Вам не хочется, что бы попросту боты грузили сервер.

Comment: @KoVadim но чтобы боты увидели тег meta, они всё равно будут вынуждены зайти на страницу и, как следствие, запустить тяжёлые скрипты

Comment: @Mike что Вы подразумеваете под "на странице персональные данные"? Вы имеете в виду, что у меня прямо на странице, допустим в теге p написана какая-то личная информация? Я Вас правильно понял?

Comment: Один раз зайдут. А потом больше не будут.

Comment: Зачем на странице вымещать какие-то личные данные?  Просто как я понял, поисковые системы индексируют содержимое страницы(текст находящийся на самой странице) и заносят в базы данных. И насколько я понял индексация страницы влияет на выдачу её(страницы) в результатах поиска.

Comment: @KoVadim боюсь, будут регулярно заходить проверять, а не обновился ли тег meta

Comment: Если честно я не совсем понимаю о каких скриптах идёт речь)))

Comment: Точнее вообще не понимаю)

Comment: Ну или например у вас есть две страницы, у который контент схож. Но для сео продвижение например вредно дублировать контент, поэтому одну страницу мы закроем от индекса, чтобы не навредить.

Comment: Короче это по большей степени к сео имеет отношение.

Comment: А зачем вообще индексация страницы нужна? Что это даёт?

Comment: @JustLearn Я имею ввиду любые данные, которые вы не хотели бы показывать поисковикам. А индексация дает то, что поисковик может ее найти по каким либо словам, которые на ней содержатся

Comment: @JustLearn попадание в выдачу поисковую, вот что это даёт.

Comment: @Mike не совсем понятно. Можете привести пример? Просто я не совсем понимаю, что на странице может быть такого, чего я не захочу показывать поисковикам.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev значит я правильно догадывался) Но если индексация даёт попадание в поисковую выдачу, то зачем тогда её отменять? Я не совсем понял Ваш предыдущий комментарий. Расскажите пожалуйста поподробнее)

Comment: Вам нужно копать в сторону СЕО, так просто не объяснить зачем это надо делать.

Comment: @JustLearn Например вы выложили на страницу порноролик со своим участием и рассылаете ссылку на него друзьям. Когда друзья захотят  открыть эту ссылку у себя в хроме с определенными настройками, он сообщит гуглу о существовании такой страницы и тот ее проиндексирует. после чего о существовании вашего ролика уже будет знать весь мир а не только те, кому вы послали ссылку и вы вероятно хотите этого избежать. Я это к тому, что на самом деле у людей может быть множество того чего они хотели бы где то разместить но при этом не хотели бы слишком широко афишировать

Comment: @Mike хороший пример :D НУ вроде немного понятно, но по всей видимости, как и сказал Alexander Semikashev мне нужно отдельно изучать SEO, чтоб в этом разобраться. Всем спасибо за ответы. В дальнейшем разберусь с SEO)))

Answer (score 1):

> Вопрос заключается в следующем: зачем атрибуту content присваивать
>   значение noindex, т.е. зачем поисковой системе запрещать индексировать
>   страницу?

Ответ: я верстаю сайты на фрилансе, на время разработки всегда добавляю данный тег, я даже всегда добавляю комментарии, чтобы заказчик не забыл его убрать, выглядит так:

```
<!-- begin Удалить <meta name="robots"-->
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<!-- end Удалить <meta name="robots"-->
```

Делается это потому, что во время создании вёрстки я показываю заказчику эту самую вёрстку на своём домене и вот, чтобы там она не была проиндексирована поисковиками, добавляется данный тег на каждую страницу.
Далее после сдачи работы заказчику, данная вёрстка отправляется в моё портфолио, также с данным тегом, чтобы она всё также не была проиндексирована у меня.

Видимо есть ещё другие варианты для использования данного тега, я описал свой, который использую постоянно, впрочем, полагаю как и большинство верстальщиков.

---

Во время вёрстки сайта, она часто проверяется в разных там онлайн-сервисах, как то: HTML-валидатор, различные сервисы проверки оптимизации и скорости загрузки страницы, например есть ещё такая AMP-вёрстка, там проверяется на специализированном сервисе. И вот, когда ты прописываешь запрет в robots.txt, то один или несколько подобных сервисов не могут просканировать страницу, мой же вариант работает всегда. Также добавлю для тебя ещё: для заказчика вёрстки должна быть возможность самостоятельно проверить твою вёрстку, всё в тех же онлайн-сервисах, для него это должно быть простой операцией, поэтому не видится никакого обходного пути.

Comment: Эм.. Вроде как для этих целей вполне можно использовать файлик robots.txt, а не заставлять заказчика из каждого файла удалять мета-тег (который он ещё и забудет удалить или удалит неправильно).